# How to write a javascript that calculates total sum per customer from json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm still a beginner with javascript and node and I have a problem.
I have file which contains payment api and I need to calculate the total sum each customer owes.
File looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "paymentId": "fc3a34e6-885e-4baf-8c67-3eeb4c3cd945",
    "customer": "Customer1",
    "amountInEur": 97
  },
  {
    "paymentId": "00320009-d2d2-43de-8ac3-a82bad36f718",
    "customer": "Customer2",
    "amountInEur": 51
  },
  {
    "paymentId": "cd44a829-e915-4f85-95bf-fe82dcd5df15",
    "customer": "Customer3",
    "amountInEur": 57
  },
  {
    "paymentId": "59c2405a-7fc2-435e-a9b1-3065f783869c",
    "customer": "Customer2",
    "amountInEur": 64
  },
```

...and the list goes on. Customer may appear on the list several times. So I need to calculate how much each customer ows.

This is what I have so far

```
const fs = require("fs");

try {
  const jsonString = fs.readFileSync("./logs.json", "utf8");
  const data = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  console.log(data);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

So I can get the data from the json file and I can even count the total amount, but  how do I calculate total amount for each customer?

Comment: Consider a loop that creates new objects for each entry, checks to see if the customer already exists, and if so, adds their amount to the object instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the `.reduce()` to transform the array that you receive from running `JSON.parse()` into an object, where keys are customer string and values - how much do they owe, like so:

```
const array = [
    {
      "paymentId": "fc3a34e6-885e-4baf-8c67-3eeb4c3cd945",
      "customer": "Customer1",
      "amountInEur": 97
    },
    {
      "paymentId": "00320009-d2d2-43de-8ac3-a82bad36f718",
      "customer": "Customer2",
      "amountInEur": 51
    },
    {
      "paymentId": "cd44a829-e915-4f85-95bf-fe82dcd5df15",
      "customer": "Customer3",
      "amountInEur": 57
    },
    {
      "paymentId": "59c2405a-7fc2-435e-a9b1-3065f783869c",
      "customer": "Customer2",
      "amountInEur": 64
    },
];

const amountsByEachCustomer = array.reduce((amountsByEachCustomer, item) => {

    // Initialize the amount to 0 when encounter customer for the first time in the loop
    if (typeof amountsByEachCustomer[item.customer] === "undefined") {
        amountsByEachCustomer[item.customer] = 0;
    }

    amountsByEachCustomer[item.customer] += item.amountInEur;

    return amountsByEachCustomer;
}, {});

console.log(amountsByEachCustomer); // { Customer1: 97, Customer2: 115, Customer3: 57 }
```